# Add dynamic class name using jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I have this code example

```html
<div class="my-blocks">
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and want to add class dynamically in ".block" class siblings elements like (bottom code example) using jQuery. Is it possible?

```html
<div class="my-blocks">
    <div class="block block-1">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-3">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Have you read the documentation of [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)?

Comment: Loop and add class with index added `$('.block').each(function (i, k){$(this).addClass('block-' + (k + 1))})`

Comment: @Andreas I tried a bit with for-loop. just started learning. Here I'm try to learn the best way to do this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-function) callback

```js
$('.my-blocks .block').addClass(function (i) {
  return 'block-' + ++i
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-blocks">
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well two functions is needed:

`.addClass()`
`.nextAll`

When you locate your first block, then use nextAll and specify `.block` class within it, to find next all sibilings, and then use `addClass` to append dynamicly class on need.

Comment: Each `.block` has different class!

Comment: Read: https://api.jquery.com/nextall/ it works also without specifying class, just you have to locate first element, and then nextAll will do the thing

Comment: Why `.nextAll()`? `.addClass()` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below example helps:

```js
$(function(){
   $('.my-blocks').find('div.block').each(function(index){
      $(this).addClass('block-'+(index+1));
   })
   
   console.log($('.my-blocks').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-blocks">
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```